# lvalue required as left operand of assignment while type casting

Tags: c, casting

I am trying to write some code, which does some calculations based on variables the user gives. The variables can be of sevral types, among them Integer or Decimal, which is where the problem lies. When I do a calculation, I declare the numbers to be calculated and the result as `double`. Though, when BOTH numbers are integers, I want the result to also be an `int`. That said, I tried typecasting, by saying the following:

```
float result;
float num1, num2;
if (strcmp(varray[var1].type, "Integer\n") == 0 && flag != 1){              
    if (varray[var2].type[0] == 'I'){
        (int)num1 = atoi(varray[var1].value);
        printf("The result type is Integer \n");
        (int)num2 = atoi(varray[var2].value);
        (int)result = num1 + num2;
        printf("Result =%d\n", result);
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

I get compiler errors on the lines where I type cast to (int), with the message displayed on the title. Am I doing something wrong here? Should I just declare the numbers and result in the conditional, and not declare them before it and type cast within?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(int)num1` is considered an *rvalue,* so called because it's expected to be on the right side of an assignment statement.

If you wanted to cast the right side to something more suitable for the variable on the left, the right side is where you would do it, such as:

```
num1 = (float) atoi (varray[var1].value);
```

This is perfectly valid though you may lose precision if your integers are large enough<sup>1</sup>. It's also unnecessary since C will happily convert it for you auto-magically. You can just use:

```
num1 = atoi (varray[var1].value);
```

You also have a problem with lines like this:

```
float result = 32.0f;
printf("Result =%d\n", result);
```

If your format specifiers don't match the types of the parameters, the behaviour is undefined. In this case, you're specifying an integer with `%d` but giving a floating point value.

If you want to print a floating point value with no decimals, you use `%.0f` as a format specifier (`%f` on its own will give a default number of digits after the decimal point, like `32.000000`).

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless you're using arrays of millions of floating point values and space is tight, or you're on a system where there's a clear and needed performance benefit to using `float`, you really should prefer doubles where possible. Their range and precision are much better.

Comment: Alright, I did that. Problem is, when I do `num1 = atoi (varray[var1].value);
`, num1 becomes equal to 0. Equal to 0, as in `printf("%d", num1);` outputs 0. Meanwhile `printf("%f", num1);` DOES actually output 32.00000. Before that, I've had a for loop print out the value of `varray[var1].value` character by character, and it's 3,2,\0. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Luke, `num1` isn't be equal to zero, it's actually because you're using the incorrect format specifier in `printf` - the specifier for a float is `%f`, `%d` is only for integers.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point behind casting the numbers/result. I want the printf to output 32, not 32.00000 when both the numbers are integers. Can that actually be done? If either is a "Decimal", the if displayed above continues normally to make calculations.

Comment: @Luke, that would be using the format `.0f` meaning no digits after the decimal point. For your case, `float f = 32.0f; printf("%.0f\n",f);` gives `32`.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. Let me actually rephrase my last comment: I know it CAN be done, but I'd rather not mess with strtok if I don't have to, since I'm not quite familiar with it yet. The way you suggested is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the rvalue (the result of atoi) instead of the lvalue (num1):

```
num1 = (float)atoi(varray[var1].value);
```

Comment: And what about the result? Should I not cast that at all?

Comment: @LukeSykpe What do you mean by "the result"?

Comment: The variable `result`

Comment: No - you don't need to cast "result" at all.  BTW: Another problem: BAD: `printf("Result =%d\n", result);`; CORRECT: `printf("Result =%f\n", result);`.  You must use the appropriate format specifier for the appropriate type ("f" for float, "lf" for double, "d" for int, etc).

Comment: Yes, I know. That was an attempt for it to output, for example `32` instead of `32.00000`. I am fully aware of the correct types. The problem is now solved though. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So I'm guessing you also know the correct way to show "integer 32" instead of "floating point 32.0000" is `printf("Result =%d\n", (int)result);`?  Or the correct way to show "float 32 with no decimal places" is printf("Result =%0f\n", result);`?  And most important: 1) Make sure you use the correct format specifiers with the right datatypes, and 2) if you cast, then cast the correct parts of the expression?

Comment: Actually, you don't _need_ to cast the return value either, C is perfectly capable of assigning an `int` to a `float` without explicit casting.

Comment: The OP needs to cast "float result" if he wants to printf with "%d" format specifier (truncating the decimal fractiont).

Comment: Foggy, I was referring to your answer where you state they need to cast int to float, rather than the comment. I should have made that clearer.